# How preserve space separated groups in bash

Tags: string, bash

I want to build a string with contains quoted groups of words.
These groups should go to same function argument.
I tried to play with arrays.
Literally constructed arrays works, but I still hope to find 
a magic syntax hack for bare string.

```
# literal array
LA=(a "b c")

function printArgs() { # function should print 2 lines
  while [ $# -ne 0 ] ; do print $1 ; shift; done
}

printArgs "${LA[@]}" # works fine
# but how to use string to split only unquoted spaces?

LA="a \"b c\""
printArgs "${LA[@]}" # doesn't work :(
LA=($LA)
printArgs "${LA[@]}" # also doesn't work :(
```

bash arrays have a problem they are not transferable over conveyor
-  (echo/$()).

Comment: Of course not. If it *were* possible, there would be no need for arrays.

Answer (score 0):

A dirty approach would be :

```
#!/bin/bash
LA=(a "b  c")

function printArgs()
{ # function should print 2 lines
  while [ $# -ne 0 ]
  do
   echo "${1//_/ }" #Use parameter expansion to globally replace '_' with space
  #Do double quote as we don't want to have word splitting
   shift
  done
}

printArgs "${LA[@]}" # works fine

LA="a b__c" # Use a place holder '_' for space, note the two '_' for two spaces
printArgs $LA #Don't double quote '$LA' here. We wish word splitting to happen. And works fine :-)
```

**Sample Output**

```
a
b  c
a
b  c
```

Note that the number of spaces inside grouped entities are preserved

---

**Sidenote**

The choice of place-holder is critical here. Hopefully you could find one that won't appear in the actual string.